# Meteor template rendered twice

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client `Template.payment.onRendered` gets fired twice, which calls the server side method twice, How can I only get it to fire the backend method once if it must do the rendering twice, else how can it get it to render only once? thx

```
//client
Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': (event) => {
    let menuShortName = event.currentTarget.dataset.template;
    Session.set('taskSelected', menuShortName);
    Meteor.call('mainAction', menuShortName);
  }
});

Template.index.helpers({
  'taskInputs': function () {
    let task = Session.get('taskSelected');
    let tasks = task ? task.split(',') : [];
    let data = DisplayCol.find({action: {$in: tasks}}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}}).fetch();
    return {items: data};
  }
});

//server
  'mainAction': function (menuShortName) {
    DisplayCol.remove({userId: this.userId});
    lib.displayMakeUp({'action': menuShortName});
  },

      'displayMakeUp': (doc) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < attrItems.length; i++) {
        if (attrItems[i].action === doc.action || attrItems[i].action.indexOf(doc.action + '_') >= 0) {
          let group = {};
          group = attrItems[i];
          group.userId = Meteor.userId();
          console.log(JSON.stringify(group));
          DisplayCol.insert(group);
        }
      }
    },


 Template.payment.onRendered(function () {
   Meteor.call('getClientToken', function (error, clientToken) {
     if (error) {
       console.log(error);
     } else {
       braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
         container: "payment-form", // Injecting into <div id="payment-form"></div>
         onPaymentMethodReceived: function (response) {
           var nonce = response.nonce;
          console.log(nonce);
      }
    });
 }
});
});
```

Templates:

```
<body>
  {{> header}}
  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{#if isVerified}}
      {{> index}}  <-------------------------- (1) 
    {{else}}
      <br><br><br><br>
      <p>Check your email for your verification link!</p>
    {{/if}}
  {{else}}
    {{> terms}}
  {{/if}}
</body>

<template name="index">
  <div id="main">
    {{#if (display 'mainMenu')}}
      {{> mainMenu}}
    {{else}} {{#if (display 'content')}}
      {{> Template.dynamic template="content" data=taskInputs}}  <------------------- (2)
      {{#if (session 'showFooter')}}
        {{> footer}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}{{/if}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="content">
  {{> subMenu}}
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
      <form>
        <button type="submit" style="display:none"></button>
        {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
          {{#each this.items}}
            {{> sub}}  <---------------------------------- (3)
          {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="sub">
 {{#if isEqual element "payment"}}
    {{> payment}}  <--------------------------------------- (4)
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="payment">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <br>
        <div id="payment-form"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your `"getClientToken"` method server only or both client and server?

Comment: Defined on the server, and called by the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I see, it looks like you are rendering the template inside an `each` block.  This will render one instance of your template for each `each` iteration.

```
{{#each this.items}}
  {{> sub}} <---------------------------------- (3) 
{{/each}}
```

Keep in mind that each template instance will fire all its callbacks (including `onRendered`).  If you only want one instance then take it out of the `each`

Comment: But there is only one document for the `payment` template in the collection which supplies the data. And I checked that it only looped once when the document is added. Each document is a html element thus I am able to easily add element to the html by modifying the documents supplied. I will try post the code.

Comment: Hmmm...so you only end up with 1 submit button rendered when you load the page?

Comment: Yes. Only one submit button. See the image I will post soon showing 2 payment forms instead of the only one expected but one button.

Comment: Not to sound silly, but is there any chance you are writing to the console from whatever template's onRendered callback that is creating your 2 paypal forms and that is what you are seeing?

Comment: I pasted the actual code for Template.payment.onRendered

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this package](https://github.com/Konecty/meteor-nrr) to limit rendering. You can also yield sub to payment (instead of checking the element) try checking if this is the first run inside your route.

```
  //html
  {{> yield sub}}

  //router
  if (Tracker.currentComputation.firstRun) {
    this.render("payment",{to:"sub"});
  }
```

Comment: This is a one page app, not using router. So `{{> yield sub}}` instead of `{{> sub}}` gave many browser errors and page did not load. 
I added konecty:nrr package and replaced `{{> sub}}` with `{{#nrr nrrargs 'sub' element=element}}{{/nrr}}`, If I did it correctly, some templates does not get rendered at all, particularly the payment template in question.